# search a letter in a word in the first list and replace with a true word in second list in python

Tags: python

I want to write a program that takes two arguments from the input, the first argument being a sentence (string) and the second argument being a list of words.
In one part of the problem, if a word in a sentence can match one of the words in the list by replacing, adding, or deleting a character, that word must replace the correct word in the list.
I do not know how to define it if it is a letter in the middle of a word!

```
enter code heredef listToString(s):    
str1 = " "      
return (str1.join(s)) 
str_True=input("please enter true string :")
lst_True=[]
main_lst=[]
while True:
    word=input("please enter a word:")
    if word=="end":
       break
    else:
        lst_True.append(word)
lst_str=list(str_True.split(" "))
print(lst_str)
for i in range(len(lst_str)):
    for j in range(len(lst_True)):
        if (len(lst_str)) > 2 and lst_str[i]!=lst_True[j]:
           if lst_str[i]==lst_True[j][:-1] or lst_str[i]==lst_True[j][1:] or 
lst_True[j]==lst_str[i][:-1] or lst_True[j]==lst_str[i][1:] or lst_str[i]==lst_True[j] 
[:j]+lst_True[j][j+1:] or lst_True[j]==lst_str[i][:i]+lst_str[i][i+1:]:
               lst_str[i]=lst_True[j]                    
 print(lst_str)
 print(listToString(lst_str))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are telling is the Levenshtein Distance. The Levenshtein distance is a similarity measure between words, where given 2 words it measures the numbers of insertions, deletions or replacements to transform one word to another.

So you can do something like:

```
def levenshteinDistanceDP(token1, token2):
    distances = [[0]*(len(token2)+1) for _ in range(len(token1)+1)]

    for t1 in range(len(token1) + 1):
        distances[t1][0] = t1

    for t2 in range(len(token2) + 1):
        distances[0][t2] = t2

    a = 0
    b = 0
    c = 0

    for t1 in range(1, len(token1) + 1):
        for t2 in range(1, len(token2) + 1):
            if (token1[t1-1] == token2[t2-1]):
                distances[t1][t2] = distances[t1 - 1][t2 - 1]
            else:
                a = distances[t1][t2 - 1]
                b = distances[t1 - 1][t2]
                c = distances[t1 - 1][t2 - 1]

                if (a <= b and a <= c):
                    distances[t1][t2] = a + 1
                elif (b <= a and b <= c):
                    distances[t1][t2] = b + 1
                else:
                    distances[t1][t2] = c + 1

    return distances[len(token1)][len(token2)]
```

Now your code:

```
str_True = set(input("please enter true string :").split()) # We will use set for faster queries and to avoid duplicates.
lst_True = []

while True:
    word=input("please enter a word:")
    if word == "end":
        break
    else:
        lst_True.append(word)

original = lst_True.copy()


for i in range(len(str_True)):
    if not lst_True[i] in str_True:  # if the word is already on the set, it already meets the conditions.
        for word in str_True:
            if levenshteinDistanceDP(lst_True[i], word) <= 1:
                lst_True[i] = word

print("Original:", *original)                
print("Result:", *lst_True)
```

You can learn more here: https://blog.paperspace.com/implementing-levenshtein-distance-word-autocomplete-autocorrect/